# Delete from point to beginning of the line

Tags: deletion, kill-text

Have read the GNU manuals on erasing, killing, and deleting.

In bash `C-u` deletes from the cursor to the beginning. I have searched and in much disbelief can't find out what the equivalent is in emacs? Very often in a buffer and in the minibuffer I wish to delete from the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: The equivalent is `C-SPC C-a C-w`

Comment: Bash's `C-u` comes from GNU readline and can be configured via `.inputrc`. `man bash` and `man readline` refer to this key combo as `unix-line-discard`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is `C-0 C-k` or `C-u 0 C-k`.

See section (info "(emacs) Killing by Lines").

Comment: Wow such a long keychord.

Comment: Keys are a scarce commodity, so emacs doesn't want to "waste" one unless it's absolutely necessary. If you don't like what's offered, you can add the command(s) needed to do what you want to the key(s) of your choice: see [Key Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html#Key-Bindings) in the Emacs manual.

Comment: I think this answer would improve slightly with the removal of the word "possibly" from the first sentence. I'd also put `C-0 C-k` first, since it seems easier to type to me.

Comment: `C-0 C-k` does not work on macOS Big Sur. Could you replace it with `M-0 C-k`? Further more, it will be better if you provide the link of your ref.

Comment: A possible [reference to "backward kill line"](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackwardKillLine)

Comment: Given all basic buffer operations chords are even longer (I'm looking at `C-x k RET` for example) this doesn't seem long by Emacs standards at all.

Answer (score 1):

`M-0 C-k` should do what you want.

Comment: This seems to duplicate @marco's earliser answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have `C-<backspace>` bound to the following function:

```
(defun phg/kill-to-bol ()
  "Kill from point to beginning of line."
  (interactive)
  (kill-line 0))
```

Basically just the `C-u 0 C-k` from the other answer, see [`kill-line`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Killing-by-Lines.html).